# Stacked denoising autoencoders. What input goes in the second autoencoder?

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders

Consider a stacked autoencoder setup where I have

```
Autoencoder1: noisy input > encoder > bottleneck1 > decoder
Autoencoder2: bottleneck1 output > encoder > bottleneck2 > decoder
```

When training the first autoencoder I'm using as input a noisy version of the original input, but what should I do with the second autoencoder? What I'm doing now is getting the output of bottleneck1 (with noisy input - the same input used for the initial training), applying noise again and using this to train the second autoencoder.

Is this correct or in the second autoencoder I should apply the noise to the output of bottleneck1 using the non-noisy input?

Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way in which you are creating this structure is not what is understood as a stacked autoencoder.

Autoencoders with multiple hidden layers are called stacked autoencoders or deep autoencoders.*

*See Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and Tensorflow by Aurélien Géron for a good overview of the different types of autoencoders.  He actually has an example of a stacked denoising autoencoder in there.

Answer (score 0):

For stacked denoising autoencoders you apply the encoding function learned by the first autoencoder to the clean input. You then use the resulting representation to train the second autoencoder as usual, adding the noise to it.

See [Stacked Denoising Autoencoders: Learning Useful Representations in a Deep Network with a Local Denoising Criterion](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1756006.1953039) for a full explanation (Figure 3 gives an overview of the training process.)